# My question about the question itself of K&R C book exercise 6.2

Tags: c

When I was finishing exercise 6.2, this is what it says:

> Exercise 6-2. Write a program that reads a C program and prints in alphabetical order each group of variable names that are identical in the first 6 characters, but different somewhere thereafter . Don’t count words within strings and comments. Make 6 a parameter that can be set from the command line.

Unfortunately I was NOT able to understand something like this

> prints in alphabetical order each group of variable names that are identical in the first 6 characters

Could someone explain it a bit to me? Given the c program I am about to read is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char line[MAXLINE];
   long lineno = 0;
   int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;
   while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-'){
       while (c = *++argv[0]){
           switch(c){
               case 'x':
                  except = 1;
                  break;
               case 'n':
                  number = 1;
                  break;
               default:
                  printf("find: illegal option %c\n", c);
                  argc = 0;
                  found = -1;
                  break;
           }
       }
   }
   if (argc != 1)
           printf("Usage: find -x -n pattern\n");
   else
       while(my_getline(line,MAXLINE) > 0){
           lineno++;
           if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except){
               if (number)
                   printf("%ld", lineno);
               printf("%s", line);
               found++;
           }
       }
   return found;
}
```

Hope the C program to be read is not complex.

Comment: If you find variables named "abcdefx", "abcdefy" and "abcdezz", you get two groups: one starting with "abcdef" containing two names and one startig with "abcdez" containing one name.

Comment: I am confused by the fact that this seems to a) be on a beginners level of string handling b) require writing a C parser. Something is odd about that contrast.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't think the intent is to require a full C parser, just a simple lexical scanner that looks for identifiers. See the `getword()` function earlier in chapter 6.

Comment: AFAICS, there are only three identifiers that are longer than 6 characters in the sample code — and they're `MAXLINE`, `my_getline` and `default`.  Of those, `default` is technically a keyword.  There are longer words in the strings, though — the analyzer must recognize (at least basic) strings.

Comment: @KeithThompson You saying that soothes my worries a little. However, even if you do have an identifier-finder, you'd still have to tell functions, types, macros, keywords, .... from the only category of identifiers needed for this, variables. While it might not be a full parser, it gets close enough to still make me worry.

Comment: @Yunnosch I suggest that if the intent were to include variable names and exclude other identifiers, they wouldn't have bothered to say "Don’t count words within strings and comments", since that would be implicit. (This seems to be an actual example of "the exception that proves the rule". By explicitly stating that words within strings and comments aren't counted, they imply that other words are counted.) Actually detecting "variable names" (it's not even clear what a "variable" is in C) would, I think require a complete preprocessor and a full parser with symbol table (typedefs are hard).

Comment: @KeithThompson You see? We start discussing issues of clarity of phrasing of the exercise. That is why I did and do worry.

Comment: Especially if the C source uses `"int abc,\n    def,\n    ghi;"` that's going to be a pickle to parse without a Lexer..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I believe the `getword()` function earlier in the chapter would give you `int`, `abc`, `def`, and `ghi`. And I believe the intent of the exercise (though it's not stated clearly) is that that's sufficient. If you're referring to recognizing that `abc` is a variable name and not a function name, a lexer wouldn't be enough; you'd need a full parser.

Answer (score 2):

> prints in alphabetical order each group of variable names that are identical in the first 6 characters

> Could someone explain it a bit to me?

My understanding is that you need to parse the C-code and identify all variable names. Then you need to identify names starting with the same 6 characters and put them groups.

Simple example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int bbbbbb2 = 42;
    int aaaaaa2 = 41;
    int bbbbbb1 = 43;
    int aaaaaa1 = 44;
    printf("%d\n", aaaaaa2*aaaaaa1  + bbbbbb2/bbbbbb1);
    return 0;
}
```

This program has 4 variables:

```
    bbbbbb2 aaaaaa2 bbbbbb1 aaaaaa1
```

There are two groups:

```
Group bbbbbb: bbbbbb2 bbbbbb1 
Group aaaaaa: aaaaaa2 aaaaaa1
```

so your sorted output must be something like

```
Group aaaaaa
------------
    aaaaaa1
    aaaaaa2

Group bbbbbb
------------
    bbbbbb1
    bbbbbb2
```

To implement this I would probably start with these steps:

1. Parse file and identify all variable names. When a variable is found, add the name to a dynamic array of strings.
2. Use qsort to sort the array
3. Remove duplicate names from the array (maybe create a new array with the unique names)
4. Iterate the array of unique variable names and print the groups